# error when convert JSON to Dictionary Swift

Tags: swift

can you help me,
 I'm facing an issue if the JSON came with multilines like this

```
"{\"groupId\":\"58\",\"chat\":\"send 2lines\nsecondline\"}"
```

I'm taking the response from server and convert it with this function

```
    let dataDic = self.convertToDictionary(text: (remoteMessage.appData["message"]! as AnyObject) as! String)
    print(dataDic!)
```

and this is my function

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
            return json

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

but the problem came if the code have multilines because it's put \n in the return and
 it gives me

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format 

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 145." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 145.}
```

Comment: Same problem as here probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247981/unescaped-control-character-around-character-981-error-while-parsing-json

Comment: You should use the triple double quote String syntax to avoid having to manually escape the special characters in your JSON string. `let json = """
{"groupId":"58","chat":"send 2lines\nsecondline"}"
"""`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string

Comment: the backspace characters comes when I convert JSON to DICTIONARY. so I should keep this formatting :(

Comment: No the backspaces aren't actually there. It is just how it is displayed

Comment: You should take some time and read Apple's Swift Book edition 4.0.3

Comment: `if let message = remoteMessage.appData["message"] as? String {"`

Comment: `let data = Data(text.utf8)`

Comment: `return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]`

Comment: And make your method throw

Answer (score 0):

You should put an extra "\" before "\n", before parsing your JSON. Try using "replacingOccurencesOf" function.
That way your JSON is formatted before parsing.